# Finding duplicate records based on a TaxKey

Tags: cognos-11

I have a some data with a Tax Key, along with their name, address, etc.  There are duplicate TaxKey's which I have been tasked to write a report for.  I have tried the filters, by doing COUNT(Taxkey) > 1, but it doesn't bring up any data.  Can someone explain it to me (like I am a child) on how to pull this data in Cognos?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on another blog.

Count(rows for [TaxKey]

Then I added a filter to the report:  CountTaxKey >=2